# What is the test command while creating package.json?

Tags: node.js, package.json

While creating `package.json` from command line using `npm init` for creating a module in Node.js, there is a **test command** field that I don't know about. There's no mention of it in the docs too on executing `npm help json` also in the CLI.

Please explain what it is about.

Comment: In short, if you have a popular tool for running the tests, the test command is likely just the name of the tool... i.e.`jest`.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The `test command` is the command that is run whenever you call `npm test`.

This is important when integrating with continuous integration/continuous deployment tools (such as `jenkins`, `codeship`, `teamcity`).

**Example:**
- say you deploy a project to AWS or some other cloud hosting provider,
- you can set up your infrastructure to automatically run `npm test`.
- If there are problems within those tests, your ci/cd will automatically rollback before deploying.

**To execute tests**
You can use *karma*, *jest*, or *selenium/nightmare/phantomjs* or about any other test scripting library/framework that allows you to write and execute tests and then set the required command in scripts.test and finally run it from `npm test`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a function here?

Comment: *changed wording from `function` to `command`

basically think, say you wanted to run `mocha test.js` - there's no point to typing that every time you want to run `mocha`

Comment: what you can do, it add npm precommits/postcommits to run `npm test` to ensure your tests pass

Comment: Okay, got it! Thanks!

Comment: One more question! What are these made of? I mean what if my application uses more than one module? Do I write tests for every module to check its own respective codes? How does it work?

Comment: What do you mean, more than one module? What it may sound like, is unit and spec tests (ie tests that are isolated to one particular file and feature, say "login")... to test all features in an application, you should lookup the terms e2e/end-to-end testing, integration testing and unit testing. Once you understand those, your test command would have npm run spec/ nom run e2e and other commands that test your entire application

Comment: I mean to say that if I'd have created a js file with two imports, each of different module, used in the same file, then how am I supposed to test that js?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148264/discussion-between-denis-tsoi-and-aakash-verma).

Comment: what are we supposed to enter at the test command when it prompts us ?

Answer (score 26):

Assuming you mean `scripts.test`:

```
"scripts" : {
  "test" : "echo 'Error: no test specified'; false"
}
```

This field contains the program(/command line) that should run when you call `npm test`. Typically, that program is a test-runner like `mocha`, `ava`, `jest`, ...

The default value is a placeholder that prints an error message (try running `npm test` in the same directory as your `package.json`).